# Windows Form: Display unique panel based on list selection

Tags: c#, winforms

Using a Windows Form I am trying to replicate the functionality of a "Tab Control" but instead of the panel selection being controlled by a tab selection it would be controlled by a list. Is there a built in way to produce this using neatly like the tab control or should I just check if a list value is equal to some value and if yes display panel else don't?

This is probably a dumb question so sorry for wasting anyone's time and thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no such built-in control in Winforms. Maybe you can achieve it via panels of the same location and set the `Visible` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides, you can also use tabpages in tabcontrol as "panel". Just hide the header via the code

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tabControl1.Appearance = TabAppearance.FlatButtons;
    tabControl1.ItemSize = new Size(0, 1);
    tabControl1.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;

    foreach (TabPage tab in tabControl1.TabPages)
    {
        tab.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Then select the tabpage like,

```
private void listBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem.ToString() == "tabPage2")
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage2;
    }
    //...
}
```